# permutation test for mixed effects 3-stage nested design

Tags: r, anova, lme4-nlme, permutation-test

I have a dataset that uses a 3-stage nested design, and I want to perform an ANOVA. I used lme() from the nlme package in R to fit a linear model, but I found that after doing a shapiro-Wilks test, there was evidence against normality.

How can I run a permutation test using aovp()? Or would it be best to do it "by hand" using a for loop?

Thanks for the tips!